# Sharepoint Quick Links, Opens and then closes all tabs before it

Tags: sharepoint-online, quick-links

I have a link to an internal site on my Sharepoint page. This is provided using the quick links bar. For some reason, when anyone clicks the link it opens up the tab with the correct page, but proceeds to close all other tabs before it. The link is:

```
http://focalpoint.drpgroup.com/FocalPoint/Logon/Logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2ffocalpoint
```

I have tried a `https://` version but this doesn't work and I've tried removing the `?ReturnUrl=%2ffocalpoint` but still get the same problem.

We have other internal sites that are linked like this and they all open fine.

I have added the same link to the side bar links (Home/Documents/Pages etc) part and when I click the link it open fine, no closing of anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi try to edit link to: 
http://focalpoint.drpgroup.com/FocalPoint/Logon/Logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=http://focalpoint.drpgroup.com

Answer (score 0):

Please add the link in a new page and compare the results.

1. Create a new page in SharePoint site.
2. Edit the page and insert the link.
3. Save the page.
4. Try opening the link.

Check whether there are some scripts in the page to close other tabs.